# Go-selenium: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: selenium, go

I tried going to windows firewall and opening port 4444, however this still does not work. This is the complete error I'm getting:

```
Failed to open session: Post http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session: dial tcp [::1]:4444: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

And lastly this is the package I'm using: "sourcegraph.com/sourcegraph/go-selenium". I never ran into this problem in python but I assume the whole application was allowed through the firewall, so if I could do that for go that would be great.

Edit: All my code (stolen from the github example)

```
package main

import (
    "sourcegraph.com/sourcegraph/go-selenium"
    "fmt"
)

func ExampleFindElement() {
    var webDriver selenium.WebDriver
    var err error
    caps := selenium.Capabilities(map[string]interface{}{"browserName": "firefox"})
    if webDriver, err = selenium.NewRemote(caps, "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to open session: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer webDriver.Quit()

err = webDriver.Get("https://sourcegraph.com/sourcegraph/go-selenium")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to load page: %s\n", err)
    return
}

if title, err := webDriver.Title(); err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("Page title: %s\n", title)
} else {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to get page title: %s", err)
    return
}

var elem selenium.WebElement
elem, err = webDriver.FindElement(selenium.ByCSSSelector, ".repo .name")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to find element: %s\n", err)
    return
}

if text, err := elem.Text(); err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("Repository: %s\n", text)
} else {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to get text of element: %s\n", err)
    return
}

// output:
// Page title: go-selenium - Sourcegraph
// Repository: go-selenium
}

func main() {
    ExampleFindElement()
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have something listening on port 4444 on localhost?

Comment: What do you mean? Using the go-selenium package, I am trying to create a new selenium session, which "resides" at port 4444

Comment: And it could not establish connection. It's the other side that did not accept the connection. Try telnet manually first.